# What do you understand "3 times per week" to mean in this sentence?

Tags: comprehension

> A total of 20 patients  included in this study. hCG (1,500 IU) was administered intramuscularly, 3 times per week.

**Which of is the correct:**

1. it means that they  administrated 1500 UI all together per week?
2. or does it mean that they  administrated 4500 UI  per week in total.

Comment: The sentence isn't grammatical. "*A total of 20 patients **were** included in this study*" would work.

Answer (score 1):

Your second interpretation is correct. If you wanted to give the first meaning while using the same numbers, the sentence would have to be more complicated:

> hCG (**a total of** 1,500 IU **per week**) was administered intramuscularly **in three separate doses per week**.

... or alternatively you can simply change the numbers.

> hCG (500 IU) was administered intramuscularly, 3 times per week.